# Need help with a tricky complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{1}{z^2+2},dz$$

I got this on a quiz today, and I proceeded as follows.

I substituted $3e^{iθ}$ for z to get
$$\int_{-π}^{0} \frac{i3e^{iθ}}{(3e^{iθ})^2+2},dz+\int_{0}^{π} \frac{i3e^{iθ}}{(3e^{iθ})^2+2},dz$$

Then I used u substitution to get
$$\int_{-3}^{0} \frac{1}{u^2+2},du + \int_{0}^{-3} \frac{1}{u^2+2},du = 0$$

I have a strong feeling that the u-substitution was illegal, but I plugged the integral into wolfram alpha and got 0. I'm not sure what the canonical approach here should be.

Comment: There are some amazing theorems about complex integrals which mean that (in some cases) there is no need to use the same methods as you would use for real integrals.  Have you met these yet in your course?

Comment: The $u$ substitution isn't illegal. However, you won't get an integral $-3\to0$ *in a straight line*. Rather, the path $-3\to0$ will be some curve in the complex plane. And it is true that the integral around this curve is *not* the same as the integral $-3\to0$ in a straight line. The reason is that the poles $\pm\sqrt{2}i$ are enclosed by the circular curves: to flatten them down to a straight line, you must first pass a pole and pay the toll price of a *residue*

Comment: In the substitution, the integrals are from $-3$ to $3$ and from $3$ to $-3$.  But as @FShrike mentioned, there is a path associated with this, and it is prescribed as $|z|=3$.  The value of the integral in path dependent and not solely determined by the end points.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $z^2+2=(z+\sqrt2i)(z-\sqrt2i)$, so there are 2 poles, namely $\sqrt2i$ and $-\sqrt2i$, both of which are inside the circle of radius $\sqrt3.$ Let's find the residue of $\frac{1}{(z-r_2)(z-r_1)}$ at $r_1$ by expressing $\frac{1}{(z-r_2)(z-r_1)}$ as a Laurent series in $z-r_1$ and finding the coeffient of $(z-r_1)^{-1}$. $$\frac{1}{(z-r_2)(z-r_1)}=\frac{1}{(z-r_1+r_1-r_2)(z-r_1)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{(r_1-r_2)(1+\frac{z-r_1}{r_1-r_2})(z-r_1)}$$ $$=\frac{1-(\frac{z-r_1}{r_1-r_2})+(\frac{z-r_1}{r_1-r_2})^2-...}{(r_1-r_2)(z-r_1)}$$ The coefficient of $(z-r_1)^{-1}$ in the Laurent series is $\frac{1}{r_1-r_2}$. Do this at each pole, add up and apply the appropriate theorem from complex analysis.

Comment: It's much easier to deform the contour to $|z|=R>2$ and let $R\to\infty$.  By inspection, the result is $0$.  This is tantamount to noting that the residue at infinity is $0$